# "Integration does not have a readiness condition" error Camel K (noobie)

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I am a noob trying to do a quick proof-of-concept, trying to deploy a KameletBinding into OpenShift and having a hard time deploying into my Camel K Operator.

All of my attempts are basically getting stuck on the "Creating" stage, then eventually failing with the following message:

```
Integration "redhat-test" does not have a readiness condition
```

Below is an example of a basic YAML deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: camel.apache.org/v1alpha1
kind: KameletBinding
metadata:
  name: redhat-test
spec:
  source:
    ref:
      apiVersion: camel.apache.org/v1alpha1
      name: timer-source
      kind: Kamelet
    properties:
      period: '10000'
      message: Hello
  sink:
    ref:
      apiVersion: camel.apache.org/v1alpha1
      name: log-sink
      kind: Kamelet
    properties:
      showHeaders: 'true'
```

Any chance I can get a little help from you to identify the issue here?

I've tried the same actions using the Red Hat Integration Camel K operator with no luck.

Comment: No comments from anyone? :(

Comment: Was this same question posted on Apache ML? if that's the case I think we have already sorted out the issue (it was a registry problem: https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/4130). If not, please, let me know what the operator log is showing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

@Squake is correct. The [Issue raised on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/camel-k/issues/4130) was spot on, and was the culprit behind our problem as well.

For further explanation, we quickly configured an OpenShift cluster to explore Camel-K (and some future microservices work). As this was all done in haste, configuration of the OpenShift internal registry was not completed. That proved to be the culprit behind the `Integration "redhat-test" does not have a readiness condition` error message.

There's some merit to the comments on the Github Issue saying that there should be an error message/validation within the Camel-K Operator letting people know if the Internal Registry is not configured since that is a requirement for deploying a KameletBinding. But, perhaps we too are an outlier in that setting up the OpenShift Internal Registry is such a core step in setting up OpenShift, that most people would not miss that step, and we were simply a victim of our own haste.

Whatever the "fix" (if there is one) is, the error message in the Camel-K Operator is pretty misleading as it leads you to think there is an issue in the DSL, where the problem really has to do with OpenShift. That "unknown" sparked a days-long debate between our developers and SysOps guys until we stumbled across the abovementioned GitHub Issue.

My apologies, Stackoverflow community, for not posting an Answer to this question sooner.